# NSURL from NSBundle path returns nil

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsbundle

So I'm trying to use a video as a background and I have a `.mov` file in my app and when I run this code:

```
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString * urlString = [bundle pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL * movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

if (!movieURL) {

    NSLog(@"Not valid");

}
```

I get `Not valid` in the console.  I checked `urlString` and it is giving me a url and I'm positive that the file is named correctly and is not in a directory.

[image: So its here...]

So the file is there and is copied into the source.  Not sure why this is doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use:

```
NSURL *moveiURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];
```

Better yet, use:

```
NSURL *moveURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"movie" withExtension:@"mov"];
```

Comment: Ahhhh completely missed that.  Duh!  Thank you!  Stupid mistake again on my part.  :)